# Attribute error when trying to import Spacy

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition, data-preprocessing

I have some issues when I try to import spacy. I downloaded the package and have the newest version, but still I get this error and I cannot find any answer. Maybe someone here had this problem and can help me out here.

This is the error when I do "import spacy":

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import spacy

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy_*init*_.py in ()
8
9 # These are imported as part of the API
---> 10 from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
11
12 from . import pipeline

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc_*init*_.py in ()
6
7 from .about import **name**, **version**  # noqa: F401
----> 8 from ._registry import registry

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc_registry.py in ()
----> 1 import catalogue
2
3
4 class registry(object):
5     optimizers = catalogue.create("thinc", "optimizers", entry_points=True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\catalogue.py in ()
16
17 # Only ever call this once for performance reasons
---> 18 AVAILABLE_ENTRY_POINTS = importlib_metadata.entry_points()
19
20 # This is where functions will be registered

AttributeError: module 'importlib_metadata' has no attribute 'entry_points'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It's just a problem with your metadata package. Try this since you are using conda environments:

```
conda install -c conda-forge importlib_metadata
```

If you prefer pip, you can do

```
pip uninstall importlib_metadata 
pip install importlib_metadata --force-reinstall
```